# Select for nowait update

Tags: java, oracle, select

I have a customer that needs a large number of updates done in the database.  I have finished trying to persuade them this can be done more cleanly.  They want to run a select statement with a "for update nowait" on a select row and then you they want to run the update statement.  I have tried this a number of ways but I am getting errors.

```
String selectQuery = " Select * from " + table + " where column=\'" + column + "\' FOR UPDATE NOWAIT";
String updateQuery = " UPDATE " + table + " SET newcolumn = \'" + newValue + "\' WHERE column = \'" + column + "\' ";

Connection connection = null;       

try 
{           
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUsername, dbPassword);

    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    stmt.addBatch(selectQuery);
    stmt.addBatch(updateQuery);
    stmt.addBatch(commit);
    int [] updateCounts = stmt.executeBatch();
    stmt.close();
}
```

This gets exception:

```
invalid batch command: invalid SELECT batch command 0
26736 [Thread-11_DataConversion] ERRORDTL - [1424462365738]java.sql.BatchUpdateException: invalid batch command: invalid SELECT batch command 0
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeBatch(OracleStatement.java:4462)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:213)
    at .BatchTokenizationAgent.executeJob(BatchTokenizationAgent.java:246)
    at com.yantra.ycp.agent.server.YCPAbstractAgent.executeOneJob(YCPAbstractAgent.java:392)
    at com.yantra.ycp.agent.server.YCPAbstractAgent.processMessage(YCPAbstractAgent.java:294)
    at com.yantra.ycp.agent.server.YCPAbstractAgent.run(YCPAbstractAgent.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

I have also tried:

```
String selectQuery = " Select * from " + table + " where column=\'" + column + "\' FOR UPDATE NOWAIT; UPDATE " + table + " SET newcolumn = \'" + newValue + "\' WHERE column = \'" + column + "\' ";

Connection connection = null;       

try 
{           
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUsername, dbPassword);

    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    stmt.execute(selectQuery);
    stmt.execute(updateQuery);
    stmt.close();
}
```

This gets exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:194)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:853)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1145)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1267)
```

Can someone please point in the correct direction?  Thank you so much.  This is to be one time job and just needs to work with minimum work needed.

Comment: You say that you're getting an error but you don't tell us what error you're getting.  That makes it tough to debug.  Why aren't you using bind variables?  Particularly if you're doing a large number of updates, that's going to bring Oracle to its knees (and probably cause your process to fail).  What sense is there in doing a `SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` and then immediately doing an `UPDATE` without doing anything to determine whether your `SELECT` actually locked the row?

Comment: I am doing what my customer and senior member of staff told me

Comment: So, just to be clear, they have explicitly told you that they want you to do a `SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`, ignore the results of that statement, and then do an `UPDATE` that may block?  It seems incredibly unlikely that is really what they want.  If it makes sense to do the `SELECT`, it would only make sense to do something with the result such as not doing the `UPDATE` if you know that it's going to block (or at least doing that `UPDATE` later).  Whether it would be faster to just do a single `UPDATE` and accept that it may block is a separate question.

Comment: Why are you backslash-escaping the single quotes? In the second example you're calling execute twice, but you only build one string; you cannot put two statements in one execute, and the semicolon is the invalid character it's complaining about.